# Amazon-like star ratings plugin needed. Lightweight and effective. Prefer Ajax

Tags: plugin-recommendation, comments

I'm looking for an efficiently coded plugin that will do 3 things...

1) Allow a person to rate a product when they submit a comment, based on a 5 star rating, by simply selecting the appropriate star on the 5 star icon widget.

2) List the user's rating of the product, inline with their comment.

3) List an overall product rating, based on the cumulative ratings of each rater, at the top of the post.

I can place the relevant tags inside single.php and comments.php if need be.

I like wp-postratings for the most part, but the ratings are not displayed beside each person's comment, they are just rolled up to the top, so you can't see what rating a particular reviewer gave the product. Other than that, its what I'm looking for.

Comment: How turn-key do you need it? Can you add your own features to a base plugin or do you need all the features written for you?

Comment: Hi Mike. You said below that you had written your own. Is it available for me to try?

Comment: *@Scott B* - I missed your response. If you are still interested I can dig it up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GD Star Rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/) plugin is immensely popular, and has an [entire site](http://www.gdstarrating.com/) dedicated to it.

Comment: I tried to use GD Star Ratings plugin on http://www.racing.ups.com and it was bloated, had no hooks, was poorly coded and the code just impossible to understand so I eventually threw it out and had to spend 3 days writing my own.

Comment: Mike, that's terribly disappointing to hear, but thanks for sharing with the rest of us.

Comment: it seems like the GD ratings is geared towards having readers rate a post or rate someones comments.  This is not the same as amazon where I submit a review ( much like comment in wordpress) that contains a rating.  Is this possible with GD Ratings?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this wouldn't let me add a comment. I am interested in this exact type of plugin, and I've been trying to work with GD Star Ratings all day. If anyone is interested, there are a number of hooks and filters. http://info.dev4press.com/gd-star-rating/filters.html

It basically has all the functionality that I am looking for, but like Mike said, nearly impossible to use and understand. On top of that, there is only premium support available, and that isn't cheap.

Scott - Were you ever able to find a solution? Did you discuss Mike's implementation with him?